# When did Luke Skywalker lose his virginity in Legends?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends

Who knows when he first lost it? Certainly before Mara Jade as he had girlfriends before. Definitely not on Tatooine. I'm thinking Prithi from the new Star Wars series. What about you guys?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is no clear indication in EU that he has had sexual relations prior to getting married to Mara Jade (and clearly he did with her since they had a child).

*Star Wars* fandom.com has a [full list of Luke's romances](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Luke_Skywalker#Romances) but in none of the works did they show that he had a physical relationship with any of them beyond kissing.

As supporting fact, "ComicScan: Luke-ing for Love in all the Wrong Places" had a note stating that Lucasfilm issued a memo to all Star Wars writers in 1994 which stated a plan to have Luke and Mara Jade wed. Thus, all romantic interests introduced after that date were created with the understanding that the romances would ultimately, not last.

---

Bonus info: according to [rumours about upcoming March 6-released novelization of *The Last Jedi*](https://www.reddit.com/r/StarWarsLeaks/comments/7zvrmw/first_sentence_of_the_tlj_novel/), Luke was NOT married in Disney canon before getting to Ahch-To - he has a *dream sequence* where he has an imaginary wife, but it's revealed to be a "what-if" in the book.

Comment: I don't usually comment on something six months old, but in *Shield of Lies* Michael Kube-McDowell directly implies that Luke is, *ahem*, halfway up Akanah Norand Pell when they're lying in bed together. At the very least, that has to be read as them lying together naked, and it is directly implied that their relationship is about to get sexual at the end of the previous book in *The Black Fleet Crisis* trilogy, *Before the Storm*. Mara Jade also mentions Luke's relationship with Akanah in *Dark Tide: Onslaught*, in which Luke admits that he never loved Akanah.

Comment: @James should be an answer

Comment: It probably should, but the question is six months old and already has an accepted answer. Short of the questioner coming back, I think I'll just leave it as a commen.

Comment: @JamesSheridan -  that user is active on and off. I would think it's safe to post. I'd definitely upvote :)

Comment: Done. I added more detail too. Way more, actually.

Comment: Has "Luke" name something to do with "Lucas"?

Comment: @SachinShekhar: This is not the place to ask that question. You can easily find the answer by Googling, or at the very least ask it on the main-page. Not as a comment on somebody else's question.

Answer (score 21):

In *Tyrant's Test* (Book 3 of *Black Fleet Crisis*) Michael Kube-McDowell directly implies that Luke and Akanah Norand Pell had sex.

After their last scene together (in book 2, where she confesses to him she tried to find her father and he didn't remember her due to being a drug addict, and leans into him to cry and be comforted), Book 3 opens with:

> Luke awoke in Mud Sloth's sleeper with an unaccustomed warmth beside
> him and an unaccustomed memory hovering close to his thoughts. He
> stirred, **and Akanah melded her body against his again, skin touching
> skin** and coaxing slumbering senses to awaken.

> **He did not know how to talk about what had passed between them, or what
> might come of it**, but she did not ask that of him. She allowed him to
> stay in the **restful comfort of the circle of their mutual embrace**,
> making no demands, expecting no explanations. He returned that
> courtesy in kind.

> **It had been much the same the night before. Loneliness, grief,
> compassion, and a previously undiscovered hunger for a touch that felt
> like acceptance had brought them to the brink**.But by silent mutual
> consent, something had been held back. Neither of them had asked for
> or offered their deepest intimacies. And, unpressured, each had
> allowed the other to enjoy the novelty of not being alone.

Mara Jade also mentions Luke's relationship with Akanah in *Dark Tide: Onslaught*, in which Luke admits that he never loved Akanah.

In addition to this, Luke also had relationships with other women in the *EU* prior to his relationship with Mara. There was Lumiya, who was secretly an apprentice of Darth Vader, later an Emperor's Hand and the self-proclaimed Dark Lady of the Sith, between the events of *A New Hope* and *The Empire Strikes Back*. Luke had a brief relationship with Gaerial Captison during *The Truce at Bakura* and they re-ignited their fling somewhat during the events of *The Corellian Trilogy*. Luke also had a relatively long-term relationship with Callista Ming, a former Old Republic Jedi Knight, for several years between *The Jedi Academy Trilogy* and his relationship with Akanah.

As for which of these women took Luke's virginity, it is difficult to say. Luke also admitted to several relationships with Rebel women during discussions with Akanah about why he hadn't fathered any bastards, though he never went into specifics. Akanah herself was a widow, and **Luke's relationship with her is the only explicitly sexual relationship he has before his marriage to Mara Jade.** Their discussions, both before and after Luke pilots his X-Wing down her Death Star trench and fires his proton torpedoes into her thermal exhaust port (I **will** be making a high number of *Star Wars* sex jokes during this answer, you've been warned) indicate that neither were virgins prior to Akanah being impaled on Luke's lightsaber.

If Akanah wasn't the first woman to stroke Luke's Wookiee, the question becomes who succumbed to the power of Luke's Dark Side before her? As stated in the question, Luke's isolation on Tatooine makes it very unlikely he tinkered under the hoods of any T-16s while he was there, though he did have enough spare time to get his power converted in a young lady's Anchorage or bullseye a womp rat or two if he really wanted to. Still, his general idealism and naivete upon joining the Rebellion would indicate that he had never sped through Beggar's Canyon before doing so.

Luke's relationship with Gaerial was short-lived, and for much of his time with Callista, she was a Force-ghost. Still, it seems unlikely that he and Callista didn't practice the horizontal form of lightsaber combat at some point during their relationship. Even Callista, though, likely didn't take Luke's virginity. Luke met Callista when he was already 30. I don't care how much self-control being a Jedi gives him, that artificial right-hand wasn't built to take the strain that being a thirty-year old virgin would entail.

This leaves us with two possibilities; an as-yet unknown romance, probably with one of the the "Rebel women" he discusses with Akanah, or Lumiya, a relatively long-term paramour of Luke's during his formative years in the Rebellion, which just happen to coincide with Luke being in his late teens and early twenties. While I was stuck pitting my lightsaber against remotes at that age, it is when most men first experience the Force's subtle pull. Losing his virginity to Lumiya, a secret Sith, would also help explain Luke's reluctance, evidenced in his conversations with Akanah in *The Black Fleet Crisis* and Mara Jade in *Vision of the Future* (the novel he eventually proposes to Mara in) to form a long-term relationship with a woman; it can't just be that he's afraid to repeat his family history and end up fighting his son, as he tells Akanah. Having opened Lumiya's Holocron only to discover she was as evil, spiteful, and vindictive as my ex-wife would drive any man to years of border-line celibacy, no matter how lovingly Callista guided his Dreadnought.

With all that said, and all jokes about Luke's planet-destroying super-laser aside, we cannot be certain exactly which woman Luke lost his virginity to in the *EU*. It's also possible that an author, possibly Timothy Zahn, who is focusing on the inter-film period in his current works, will throw us a curveball and have Luke stick his droid in a woman's socket in an upcoming work. Still, with the evidence at our disposal, it seems that Luke likely penetrated the energy shield around Lumiya's forested moon before any others.

Comment: Do you have a quote from the book? To be honest, I just re-read the book, and I thnik the Wookiepedia quote is wholly made up. This is the entirety of the episode that I THINK they referred to:

Comment: "Words no longer offered any hope of comforting her, and her need was too acute to ignore. With a gentle tug on her hand and a meaningful, confirming look, Luke invited her into the bunk with him. After a moment's hesitation, Akanah climbed in through the gap in the curtains and curled up against him, nestled in the crook of his arm. Before long, she was sobbing quietly, her body shaking beside his. But the tears felt to Luke more like welcome relief than distress. Saying nothing, he held Akanah close and tried to wrap her in a blanket of comfort...."

Comment: Dammit, @DVK, i was just typing that out!

Comment: With that said, that's the last scene featuring the two in that book. The first scene the two have in the next book, they're lying in bed together naked. As I recently said in another answer, they weren't in there baking cookies. Luke was scorching her with his Force-lightning.

Comment: quote or it didn't happen :)

Comment: I can't quote a book I haven't owned for a year. I recall "Akanah rolled away, breaking their connection," and "she climbed out of the bunk, and into her jumpsuit." I'm still wondering how the hell you found the previous quote.

Comment: I added the quote for you and edited to conform to it. Hopefully you'll like the edit

Comment: @DVK: I noticed it, and yes, it's satisfactory. It's always a lot of work to edit one of my answers, because I always make them too damn long.

Answer (score -2):

Well really, it might only have been to Mara. Remember that before Mara and he actually got together, his great love was Dead Jedi Stuck in a 
Computer Girl, Callisto. No hot and heavy action happening there! Moreover, unlike his father, Luke seems to embrace the monastic lifestyle, at least for a while. because he is the sole reaining Jedi Master, he seems to want to do everything right and by the book, including not having romantic and sexual relationships.

Comment: " he seems to want to do everything right and by the book, including not having romantic and sexual relationships" - is that based on canon?

Comment: @DVK: He does grapple with the concept of romantic relationships violating the Jedi Code in *Survivor's Quest* and *Destiny's Way*, but both of those novels post-date his marriage to Mara Jade. He's certainly not living the monastic life when he's swapping midi-chlorians with Akanah.

Comment: "Luminous beings are we, not this crude matter."